# Using a touchscreen (ipad) without fine motor skills

Tags: ipad, accessibility

Before my wife was disabled I did not realise how difficult to use a touch screen actually is - one has to touch an icon (than cannot be enlarged, apparently) for a precise amount of time, without introducing the slightest lateral movement, else instead of triggering a "click" event it does, well, something (moving icons etc).

My wife can just about hit the screen, but she cannot control duration of touch, or keep her finger steady. So even basic interactions with the touch screen are quite impossible.

I tried to fiddle with the accessibility settings to no avail, but then I don't seem to quite understand what they are doing (because they do not seem to do anything useful).

So basically, I am looking for a touchscreen setting that translates a flailing motion into a click. Is there such a thing?

My wife cannot speak, either. I know where I can find the accessibility settings, I just can't find out how to change the settings to do what we need, provided it is even possible.

Comment: Can she use Siri?  Here's a list of the [built-in accessibility features](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/get-started-with-accessibility-features-iph3e2e4367/ios).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention. She cannot speak anymore.

Answer (score 1):

ios has several accessibility features that might help you and your wife get the most from the iPad. I would start with touch accommodations, switch control, and assistive touch based on my understanding of where your  challenges and abilities are today.

- https://www.apple.com/accessibility/
- https://www.apple.com/accessibility/ipad/mobility/