# How do disable iOS keyboard from displaying?

Tags: ios, ipad, ipados

When I press my finger down on the iPad in any app, the iOS keyboard pops up automatically. How do I disable this? It is very distracting when trying to paste text or a screenshot into OneNote for example.

iPad 12.9 2018
IOS 13.7

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. What do you mean when you press your finger on on any app?  Do you mean in non-text fields when you press the keyboard shows up or just in text fields?

Comment: just in text fields..like in OneNote, I'm trying to paste a screenshot with finger, but the keyboard pops up. I'm trying to use my ipad as a writing tool only.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the text insertion gesture may be impossible unless you consider adding an external keyboard or setting up voiceover to intercept and remap that gesture. I have had good success with peers using physical keyboards or accessories and propping up their iPad. Or use an Apple Pencil for many gestures and scribbles, which lessens the time fingers are on screen.

Hopefully over time you can train yourself and just summon the keyboard when you want it, knowing the gesture that summons it is a tap and hold.

Here are the global touch delays, if you want to experiment with them.

[image]

I find these are invaluable for teaching people to experience the sub second delays needed for a gesture to be recognized, but in the end, the penalty of slowing down the keyboard also slows down other interactions and most people don’t use these [unless they need it due to dexterity conditions that make the default timing problematic and over sensitive / too reactive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/379153/5472).